# Latest CMake and LLVM on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, llvm, llvm-clang

All

latest LLVM is 7.0 and it is working quite well on Windows 10 x64, building native executables etc.

latest CMake is 3.12.x.

I have VS 2017 Pro installed as well.

Downloaded them both and tried to make simple project with it on Windows, and it didn't work, even if I set CC/CXX, linker pointing to lld, failing on compiling test problem, not finding **rc** (resource compiler).

Tried targeting GNU make as well as Ninja as build system.

Is this a supported configuration? If yes, how to make it work?

Basically, I would like to use CMake/LLVM with editor/terminal like I'm doing it on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run CMake from [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs).
That should make **rc** available in your `PATH`, and then CMake should be able to find it.